# html table with position fixed

Tags: html, css

I using position fixed to freeze first column in table. How to make it the first column layout(width and height) same as other column to looks like no different with other columns but with freeze status.

```
<div>
 <table>
<tr>
  <th class='td1'>h1</th>
  <th>h2</th>
  <th>h3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class='td1'>D1</td>
  <td>D2</td>
  <td>D3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class='td1'>D1</td>
  <td>D2</td>
  <td>D3</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

css:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.td1 {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LtL15dau/)

Comment: use bootstrap libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below -

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

td,
th {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-top-width: 0px;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-left: 5em;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding: 0;
}

.headcol {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5em;
  left: 0;
  top: auto;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.headcol:before {
  content: 'Row ';
}

.long {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">h1</th>
      <td class="long">h2</td>
      <td class="long">h3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">D1</th>
      <td class="long">D2</td>
      <td class="long">D3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">D1</th>
      <td class="long">D2</td>
      <td class="long">D3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

CSS:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.td1 {
position: fixed;
width: 143px;
height: 96px;
margin-left: 5px;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
 <table>
<tr>
  <th class='td1'>h1</th>
  <th>h2</th>
  <th>h3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class='td1'>D1</td>
  <td>D2</td>
  <td>D3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class='td1'>D1</td>
  <td>D2</td>
  <td>D3</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```